# Are there any single logic gates which are just individual components?

Tags: components, component-selection, logic-gates

As the question says, I need a NOT gate for a simple Bi-Colour LED circuit. 
I do not want to use an IC with 6 or 7 integrated as I am only going to use 1, so it's just a waste.

So, do individual logic gates exist?

Do they have a specific name?

Note: Just so you know, I'm not looking for shopping advice. I just need to know if a component exists or not. Thanks!

Comment: Yes for example http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf

Comment: Also known as SGL (Single Gate Logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texas Instruments calls them ["Little Logic"](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/logic/little-logic-overview.page). They are found in several logic families, included but not limited to 74LVC, 74AHC, and 74AUP. Other manufacturers have similar products, sometimes also available in other families e.g. NXP's [74AXP](http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/family/AXP/).

Note that they are strictly surface mount, as those are the most likely targets for such a device.